# System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection not working as expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections

I'm implementing a collection that automatically deletes all entries that are older than a timespan. I decided to use a Concurrent.BlockingCollection and as test I made following program:

```
    namespace CollectionTester {

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            MyQueue queue = new MyQueue();
            Sender thread = new Sender(queue);
            Receiver rec = new Receiver(queue);

            thread.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            rec.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class MyQueue {
        private System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<DateTime> col = null;
        private TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 6);
        private object _lock = new object();

        public MyQueue() {
            this.col = new System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<DateTime>(5);
        }

        public System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<DateTime> TheCollection {
            get { return col; }
        }

        public void setVal(DateTime ts) {
            Console.WriteLine("try to add " + ts.ToLongTimeString());
            while (!col.TryAdd(ts)) {
                deleteOlder();
            }
            ShowContent(" ++ ");
        }

        public void ShowContent(string tag) {
            foreach (DateTime i in col) {
                Console.WriteLine(tag + " " + i.ToLongTimeString());
            }
        }

        private bool deleteOlder() {
            DateTime old = DateTime.Now;
            bool ret = false;

            foreach (DateTime item in col) {
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(item) >= timeout) {
                    col.TryTake(out old);
                    ret = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (ret == true) {
                return deleteOlder();
            }
            else {
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Receiver {
        private MyQueue theCollection = null;

        public Receiver(MyQueue thecol) {
            this.theCollection = thecol;
        }

        public void Start() {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                while (theCollection.TheCollection.Count > 0) {
                    try {
                        DateTime ts = DateTime.Now;
                        if (theCollection.TheCollection.TryTake(out ts)) {
                            Console.WriteLine(" --> " + ts.ToLongTimeString());
                            theCollection.ShowContent(" -- " );
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        }
                    } catch {
                        Console.WriteLine(" --> Error fectching Item");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing in the queue");
            });
        }
    }

    public class Sender {
        private MyQueue theCollection = null;

        public Sender(MyQueue thecol) {
            this.theCollection = thecol;
        }

        public void Start() {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i.ToString());

                    DateTime ts = DateTime.Now;
                    theCollection.setVal(ts);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing else to add...");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

this is working perfectly, but if I use the GetConsumingEnumerable enumerator, the program is blocked.

try substituting something so simple as the   with:

```
public void ShowContent(string tag) {
    foreach (DateTime i in col.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
        Console.WriteLine(tag + " " + i.ToLongTimeString());
    }
    col.CompleteAdding();
}
```

and the program will be broken.

For me, this makes no sense, the GetConsumingEnumerable should be a safer option to the standard enumerator, as it uses a copy of the collection, but it is blocking the program. I tried putting a lock and nothing change.

Am I understanding this collection in a wrong way or may this be a bug? Or do you see a flaw in my implementation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a flaw alright. `BlockingCollection` is designed to be used by at least two threads: one adding the items, the other consuming. I think you've realised that, but what you've done is created one thread that does all the work while your main thread does nothing. `Sender` calls `setVal` to add items, but then immediately reads them from the collection. This is always going to give odd results.

Instead, you need your `Sender` class to *just add* the items on a separate thread. Your main thread should call `Receiver` to read the items using `GetConsumingEnumerable`. You just need to look at some of the examples for `BlockingCollection` to get an idea of how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my example is not exactly what I really want, my real application has several threads. Do you think with several threads this collection will work properly? I will modify my example and continue trying. Thanks!

Comment: It should do, but to be honest, if all you're trying to do is remove items that have expired, I'm not sure why you need multiple threads or `BlockingCollection`s. I think maybe you just need to use a normal `List`.

Comment: because the environment is multithreaded. What I'm showing you is an example, but in my real application, there are different threads for adding and for reading the collection.

Comment: I tried with different threads and I have the same behaviour. I will put the code

Comment: And yet your `while` statement and your use of `TryTake` means you're not waiting on your consuming thread for the collection to be populated. It will immediately terminate. Honestly, multithreading like this requires a lot of discipline - follow the examples in the docs or pick an easier way to do it.

Comment: Tim, it is only a test class, I put 2 seconds delay between the start of both threads to be sure that the collection is not empty. If you copy all this code in a new console application project, you will see that is running and you maybe be able to see that GetConsumingEnumerable is not working. Have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with when you are iterating. Notice how in the following example of GetConsumingEnumerable the add is completed before looping, in order to prevent the loop from hanging... [Taken from this MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
class ConsumingEnumerableDemo
{
    // Demonstrates: 
    //      BlockingCollection<T>.Add() 
    //      BlockingCollection<T>.CompleteAdding() 
    //      BlockingCollection<T>.GetConsumingEnumerable() 
    public static void BC_GetConsumingEnumerable()
    {
        using (BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>())
        {

            // Kick off a producer task
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    bc.Add(i);
                    Thread.Sleep(100); // sleep 100 ms between adds
                }

                // Need to do this to keep foreach below from hanging
                bc.CompleteAdding();
            });

            // Now consume the blocking collection with foreach. 
            // Use bc.GetConsumingEnumerable() instead of just bc because the 
            // former will block waiting for completion and the latter will 
            // simply take a snapshot of the current state of the underlying collection. 
            foreach (var item in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good blog entry about this class, and now I really understand the use of this method:

http://www.codethinked.com/blockingcollection-and-iproducerconsumercollection

The point is that this enumerable is indeed some kind of blocking point to wait for new items and should only be used in the consumer and never as normal enumerator.

The code for my example would be now:

```
namespace CollectionTester {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            MyQueue queue = new MyQueue();
            Sender thread = new Sender(queue);
            Receiver rec = new Receiver(queue);

            thread.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            rec.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class MyQueue {
        private System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<DateTime> col = null;
        private TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 6);

        public MyQueue() {
            this.col = new System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<DateTime>(5);
        }

        public System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<DateTime> TheCollection {
            get { return col; }
        }

        public void setVal(DateTime ts) {
            Console.WriteLine("try to add " + ts.ToLongTimeString());
            while (!col.TryAdd(ts)) {
                deleteOlder();
            }
            ShowContent(" ++ ");
        }

        public void ShowContent(string tag) {
            foreach (DateTime i in col) {
                Console.WriteLine(tag + " " + i.ToLongTimeString());
            }
        }

        private bool deleteOlder() {
            DateTime old = DateTime.Now;
            bool ret = false;

            foreach (DateTime item in col) {
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(item) >= timeout) {
                    col.TryTake(out old);
                    ret = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ret == true) {
                return deleteOlder();
            }
            else {
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Receiver {
        private MyQueue theCollection = null;

        public Receiver(MyQueue thecol) {
            this.theCollection = thecol;
        }

        public void Start() {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                foreach (DateTime value in theCollection.TheCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
                    Console.WriteLine(" >>> " + value.ToLongTimeString());
                    theCollection.ShowContent(" -- ");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing in the queue");
            });
        }
    }
    public class Sender {
        private MyQueue theCollection = null;

        public Sender(MyQueue thecol) {
            this.theCollection = thecol;
        }

        public void Start() {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i.ToString());

                    DateTime ts = DateTime.Now;
                    theCollection.setVal(ts);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing else to add...");
                theCollection.TheCollection.CompleteAdding();
            });
        }
    }
}
```